# DataContext.Refresh exception

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datacontext

When I'm trying to use following codeblock:

```
    private MarketingDBDataContext DB_Marketing;

    public DBFacade()
    {
        DB_Marketing = new MarketingDBDataContext();
    }        
    public void updateSingleObj(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Marketing.Cust)
        {
            try
            {                     
                DB_Marketing.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, obj);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm getting this Exception:

```
An object specified for refresh is not recognized
```

I have a similar method with another datacontext and another entity object reference, which works fine.

I have a Marketing Cust gui, that open a new dialogwindow for entering website link. I want to check the current Marketing Cust object for change in this Weblink value, before the new DialogWindow show up.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923039/an-object-specified-for-refresh-is-not-recognized

Comment: Found it! Was a little hard to debug tho. I was using a method from another sub-controller, and I initiate a instance of my Database facade for each sub, so ofc the object didn't exist in the wrong sub-controller instance.... Stupid me! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.
Having two controllers where each having an instance of the Database facade. I try'd to re-use a method in the wrong controller, forgetting that the controller make and database facade instance for the corresponding database, which ofcause led to a DataContext, where the object didn't exist.

My tip for others, check where you instantiate your DataContext, and make sure that the object contain in it.